# Hive: Dynamic Partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Getting the following error when tried to execute the following code for dynamic partitioning in hive.

Hive Query:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE VODPARTITION(EVENT_ID string, EVENT_TYPE string, DATE string) 
PARTITIONED BY (IPADDRESS string) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' stored as sequencefile;

 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE VODPARTITION
 PARTITION(ipaddress) 
 SELECT EVENT_ID, EVENT_TYPE, DATE, t.IP_ADDRESS as ipaddress FROM VOD t;
```

Error:

```
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
```

I am getting this error after map task and 70% of reduce task is completed.
Any help on how to proceed in this case....?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Please try with below settings:

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true 

If the table has only dynamic partition columns, then the configuration setting hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode should be set to non-strict mode:

SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=non-strict;

Comment: yes. i have already executed these commands. The Error mentioned came after execution of these commands.